# Overriding the virtual functions with different return types raises error with private inheritance

Tags: c++, return-type, overriding

In the following code I got the following compilation errors:

```
1>c:\users\mittamani\desktop\06-10\over_riding_test\over_riding_test\over_riding_test.cpp(33) : error C2555: '_D1::fun': overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'Base2::fun'
1>        c:\users\mittamani\desktop\06-10\over_riding_test\over_riding_test\over_riding_test.cpp(28) : see declaration of 'Base2::fun'
1>        'Base1' : base class is not accessible
1>c:\users\mittamani\desktop\06-10\over_riding_test\over_riding_test\over_riding_test.cpp(37) : error C2555: '_D2::fun': overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'Base2::fun'
1>        c:\users\mittamani\desktop\06-10\over_riding_test\over_riding_test\over_riding_test.cpp(28) : see declaration of 'Base2::fun'
1>        'Base1' : base class is not accessible
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\mittamani\Desktop\06-10\Over_riding_Test\Over_riding_Test\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>Over_riding_Test - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Here is the code:

```
class Base1{
public:
    Base1(){}
    virtual ~Base1(){}
};

class D1:Base1{

};

class D2:Base1{

};

class Base2{
public:
    Base2(){}
    virtual ~Base2(){}
    virtual Base1 * fun() = 0;
};

class _D1:Base2{
public:
    D1* fun(){}
};

class _D2:Base2{
public:
    D2* fun(){}
};
```

By the way, I am fresher to C++.. plz help..thanks in advance..

Comment: Reading *any* tutorial or book should tell you that you can't overload on return type, only on function arguments.

Comment: Also, [don't use names with leading underscore followed by a capital letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: you are using pure virtual functions that must be implemented by the child class. Also for virtual functions the signature must be same for both child and parent class

Comment: In your case, you miss `public` in the inheritance.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg "overloading on return type" That's not the problem here, see PiotrS's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to use [*covariance of return types*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type), your attempts are valid except for the fact  that the types must be using a public inheritance:

```
class D1:public Base1{
//       ~~~~~^

};

class D2:public Base1{
//       ~~~~~^    
};

class _D1 : Base2{
public:
    D1* fun(){} // ok now, D1 inherits publicly from Base1
};

class _D2 : Base2{
public:
    D2* fun(){} // ok now, D2 inherits publicly from Base1
};
```

Just like you can't cast `D2*` to `Base1*` unless you are using a public inheritance, the same applies here.

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae78ca2fc1862876)

---

Alternatively, you would have to make those classes to be friends, so that they *have access* to the private base class:

```
class _D1;
class _D2;

class D1 : Base1{
    friend class _D1;
};

class D2 : Base1{
    friend class _D2;
};
```

---

C++ Standard reference:

> #### § 10.3 Virtual functions `[class.virtual]`
>
> 7. The return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to the return type of the overridden function or covariant with the classes of the functions. If a function `D::f` overrides a function `B::f`, the return types of the functions are covariant if they satisfy the following criteria:
>
>    — both are pointers to classes, both are lvalue references to classes, or both are rvalue references to classes
>
>    — the class in the return type of `B::f` is the same class as the class in the return type of `D::f`, or is an unambiguous **and accessible** direct or indirect base class of the class in the return type of `D::f`
>
>    — both pointers or references have the same cv-qualification and the class type in the return type of `D::f` has the same cv-qualification as or less cv-qualification than the class type in the return type of `B::f`.

Answer (score 2):

The return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to the return type of the overridden function or covariant with the classes of the functions. If a function D::f overrides a function B::f, the return types of the functions are covariant if they satisfy the following criteria:

-both are pointers to classes or references to classes
-the class in the return type of B::f is the same class as the class in the return type of D::f or, is an unambiguous direct or indirect base class of the class in the return type of D::f and is accessible in D
-both pointers or references have the same cv-qualification and the class type in the return type of D::f has the same cv-qualification as or less cv-qualification than the class type in the return type of B::f.

Answer (score -2):

You must change all the `fun()`s to return `Base1`.